# Displaying a folder in a document center from a parent site to a subsite

Tags: document, sub-site, document-center

I am looking to display a folder from a document center that is a sub site onto another sub site. I have seen a few other people with the same question but without any good answers. I am using SharePoint 2013 and am a fairly new user, so the easier the better...

Thanks!
Elin